# Ambari Server Setup: Conflict error in sudoers file

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

**Error message from Ambari Server setup**

Transaction check error:
  file /etc/sudoers.d from install of ambari-agent-2.0.0-151.x86_64 conflicts with file from package sudo-1.8.6p7-13.el7.x86_64

**Systems**

Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 7.1 (HVM)
m3.larget

**Action**

Running Ambari 2.0.0 server setup

Ambari Repo:
http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos6/2.x/updates/2.0.0/ambari.repo

Comment: I also face the same issue, could you tell me if you resolved it

Answer (score 1):

RHEL 7.x is not supported by Ambari 2.0.0. See OS requirements here:

http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.0.0.0/bk_Installing_HDP_AMB/content/_operating_systems_requirements.html